# Networking not working on ASUS F102B Netbook PC running ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, ethernet

Wireless networking on the above-mentioned computer stopped some 5 months ago.  Have only got around to troubleshooting it.

When I type `sudo lshw -C network`, two controllers - the AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter and the RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller - are reported as `UNCLAIMED`.  I understand from reading various posts here that this means the drivers aren't installed and/or running.  (Understandably, we cannot connect to our ADSL router via blue cable either.)

Output from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`: (transcribed)

```
User:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list  
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)  
        Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:6627]  
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)  
        Subsystem ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1043:200f]
```

I tried using the `GRUB` menu by pressing `Esc` while booting (`Shift` didn't work for this machine), and got a menu which said the following:

```
Please select boot device:  
ubuntu (PO: HGST HTS54503217E680)  
ubuntu (PO: HGST HTS54503217E680)  
Enter Setup  
<up> and <down> to move selection  
ENTER to select boot device
```

The sequences against the two `ubuntu` items are identical.  There was no **Advanced Options** menu item available in order to try booting using an older version of Ubuntu, thus I couldn't check if a previous version of Ubuntu on this machine had working drivers.

I would like to know the following:

1. What networking drivers should I be looking for on the computer?
2. If the drivers are present, how do I ensure they start up in future so I can use the Internet from the computer?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: There are two networking devices (one wired, one wireless) without proper kernel drivers in place that likely require entirely independent solutions which make this question a little broad. I recommend that you [split your question](/questions/ask) so we can deal with these separate issues individually and effectively. You're welcome to link the questions to each other. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and press the Shift key to get the Grub Menu to appear, then scroll to Advanced Options and boot into an older kernel.

If you have internet using the older kernel install all updates and reboot.

I suspect your last update included a kernel update but didn't install the new linux-image-extra and that is why both the wired and wireless connections are not functional.

Another option is to boot to a Live USB/DVD and follow instructions similar to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure
Once booted to the Live USB/DVD you should have internet use available again then open a terminal and enter

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

Reboot to the installed version when it is finished

Comment: Hi Jeremy31, thank you for your response.  I've edited the question per the feedback above, and included some output.  **GRUB** didn't give me the advanced options menu per my question edit above.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Tried that - it went looking for the au.archive.ubuntu.com site and said it couldn't fetch some archives.  I have copied the appropriate `linux-image-extra` `.deb` file from that site to a USB stick, but the ubuntu machine appears not to recognise the stick when I plug it in ... maybe the USB driver isn't working either?  If the `.deb` file was on the computer, where would it be located, and how would I tell ubuntu to update from there instead?

Comment: Further to my last comment: `sudo fdisk -l` shows `/dev/ram0` etc through to ram15, and `/dev/sda` partitioned into 3 devices, but nothing else with the USB stick plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone,

Thank you very much with your assistance in sorting this problem.  I've learnt a lot about ubuntu just from your answers, which also triggered many more searches for information on my part.

In the process of investigating how to build a Live USB per Jeremy31's suggestion, I discovered that the version of ubuntu loaded onto our ASUS F102B Notebook was not the optimum for such a low-spec machine.  So I've made a Live USB for Lubuntu, and am loading that onto the machine as a fresh install.

Thanks again everyone for your assistance.

Mike.